# Node (Gulp) process.stdout.write to file

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, gulp

I'm trying to have gulp taking care of my unit tests for me, and outputting my test coverage to a `.lcov` file.

This is what I have so far :

```
gulp.task('test', function () {
    var test = fs.createWriteStream('./test.lcov', {flags: 'a'});
    return gulp.src('./assets/js/test/test.js', {read: false})
        .pipe(mocha({reporter: 'mocha-lcov-reporter'}))
        .pipe(test);
});
```

The `mocha-lcov-reporter` code can be found here :
https://github.com/StevenLooman/mocha-lcov-reporter/blob/master/lib/lcov.js

It outputs results through `process.stdout.write()`

But when I pipe this to a `WriteStream` I have the following error :

```
TypeError: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk
    at validChunk (_stream_writable.js:152:14)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:181:12)
    at Stream.ondata (stream.js:51:26)
    at Stream.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at drain (/Users/braunromain/Documents/dev/should-i-go/node_modules/gulp-mocha/node_modules/through/index.js:36:16)
    at Stream.stream.queue.stream.push (/Users/braunromain/Documents/dev/should-i-go/node_modules/gulp-mocha/node_modules/through/index.js:45:5)
    at Stream.stream (/Users/braunromain/Documents/dev/should-i-go/node_modules/gulp-mocha/index.js:27:8)
    at Stream.stream.write (/Users/braunromain/Documents/dev/should-i-go/node_modules/gulp-mocha/node_modules/through/index.js:26:11)
    at write (/Users/braunromain/Documents/dev/should-i-go/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:623:24)
    at flow (/Users/braunromain/Documents/dev/should-i-go/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:632:7)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `mocha-lcov-reporter`, but did you instrument your files (https://github.com/StevenLooman/mocha-lcov-reporter#usage):
1) Install jscover or node-jscoverage
2) Instrument your library with jscover (or node-jscoverage)
3) Run your tests against your instrumented library and save the output

Answer (score 3):

Looks like gulp-mocha isn't totally set up to be a true through stream, in fact it looks like it just pipes the source into a Mocha instance and lets Mocha do it's thing.

The first thing that comes to my head just to do a simple redirect in bash...

```
$ gulp test | grep -Ev "^\[[0-9:]{0,8}\]" > ./test.lcov
```

Of course this assumes all the output that is gulp related will start with `[00:00:00]` (with the `00` being the current system time). If this isn't the case you may end up with gulp output at the top and bottom of your file.

If you're looking for a more universal answer (read: using nodejs) you can do a rewrite of `process.stdout.write`. This is probably :( upon by most but it would work. The trick is that you can't overwrite `process.stdout` as another stream because it is written as a getter internally. You can however rewrite the `stdout.write` function. As a matter of fact I just did this for a project I'm working on so I can review gulp logs of other developers in case they have issues with the build system.

I chose to go with a not so async solution because unlike most everything else in nodejs, `stdout` and `stderr` are both blocking streams and don't act like the asynchronous code you're used to. Using this technique your task would end up looking something like this:

```
gulp.task('test', function () {
  // clear out old coverage file
  fs.writeFileSync('./test.lcov', '');

  // if you still want to see output in the console
  //   you need a copy of the original write function
  var ogWrite = process.stdout.write;

  process.stdout.write = function( chunk ){
    fs.appendFile( './test.lcov', chunk );

    // this will write the output to the console
    ogWrite.apply( this, arguments );
  };

  return gulp.src('./assets/js/test/test.js', {read: false})
    .pipe(mocha({reporter: 'mocha-lcov-reporter'}));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to log everything in my gulp process to a file and ended up with this which works ok for me:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var proc = require('process');
var origstdout = process.stdout.write,
  origstderr = process.stderr.write,
  outfile = 'node_output.log',
  errfile = 'node_error.log';
if (fs.exists(outfile)) { fs.unlink(outfile); }
if (fs.exists(errfile)) { fs.unlink(errfile); }

process.stdout.write = function( chunk ){
  fs.appendFile(outfile, chunk.replace(/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m/g, ''));
  origstdout.apply(this, arguments);
};

process.stderr.write = function( chunk ){
  fs.appendFile(errfile, chunk.replace(/\x1b\[[0-9;]*m/g, ''));
  origstderr.apply(this, arguments);
};
```