# Redirect gulp lint stdout to file

Tags: gulp, tslint

I have designed a gulp task for linting of .ts files present in my project. When I run it, it shows correct output on the prompt, ***but I am not sure how to redirect that output to a file so it can be printed*** so that I can handover the complete file to developer to correct the code accordingly.

my task looks like :

```
gulp.task('lint', function() {
   gulp.src("src/**/**/*.ts")
     .pipe(tslint({
        formatter: "codeFrame",
        configuration: "./tslint.json"
    }))
    .pipe(tslint.report({
        configuration: {},
        rulesDirectory: null,
        emitError: true,
        reportLimit: 0,
        summarizeFailureOutput: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./Dest/reports'))
});
```

Could someone please suggest how do I achieve this.

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26396947/node-gulp-process-stdout-write-to-file will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [redirect via tee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418896/how-to-redirect-output-to-a-file-and-stdout) for some good examples of redirecting the stdout to a file.  It could be as simple as

```
gulp lint | tee logfile.txt
```

With that you'll get both the output in the terminal as per usual and a copy in a file, that will be created for you if necessary.  You don't say what terminal you are using though.  if that doesn't work perhaps:

```
gulp lint 1> logfile.txt
```

See [bash redirecting](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redirecting-stderr-to-stdout/) if you are using bash shell. Or [SO: bash redirecting with truncating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-can-i-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-with-bash).

The linked question also has info on stderr if you need that.

Also for a quick way to copy output to the clipboard in Powershell:

```
gulp lint | clip
gulp lint | scb             (doesn't add an extra newline at the end)
```

See [pbcopy](https://ss64.com/osx/pbcopy.html) same as clip for macOS.

In general, see [pbcopy alternatives on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/472598/pbcopy-for-windows)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mark, but I needed to write some code within the script only and not mention anything on cmd at the run time. Well, this [Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-tslint-jenkins-reporter) helped me out here